# Problems with selecting text in Intellij Idea 14

Tags: intellij-idea

friends.
I have installed Intellij-Idea 14 on my Linux Mint 17 distribution. All is great but I can't select text with Shift + arrays. The behavior of the Shift button is the same with the Ctrl button. Also the cursor is changed frequently from carret to "Insert type". Sometimes the cursor selects the text just with arrays without Shift-keypress. 
I tried to change the keymap from Settings->Appearance and Behavior, but no one of them not resolved my problem. This problem is present not only in code editor. It is present in tool windows, consoles etc. In other applications from my OS there are no problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem was in "VIM emulator". It was activated by "Ctrl + Alt + V" keypress. I deactivated it from Tools -> Vim Emulator

Comment: Still problem even changing the VIM to IDE